# A mistake in Codeigniter URL when post a form

Tags: codeigniter-url, codeigniter-routing

I am a beginner in codeigniter framework.
In codeigniter v.3 I create a form
`<?php echo form_open("login/registration"); ?>`
Current URL is "http://padpors/login"; but when I submit form, form has posted to "http://padpors/padpors/index.php/login/registration"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go to application/config/config.php

here you will find $config['base_url'];

edit the line to:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://padpors/';
```

Comment: Tnx a lot :) I set it $config['base_url'] = 'padpors'; and now it work true.